# 2004 ford taurus motor knocking when car starting

Tags: ford, noise, taurus

I have a 2004 ford taurus se. When i start my car up there is a raddle. On a scale from 1-10 the raddle is a 6 deep but not alarming. Well as soon as I start my vehicle the raddle quiets. Has anyone ran into this problem? Or may have a solution please comment.

Comment: Have you checked the oil recently?

Comment: How many miles and what engine?

Comment: Oh boy, lots of questions here.  Is the rattle tied to engine speed?  Can you hear the rattle when your car is in park or must the vehicle be moving? I don't understand the word "Start" (to me that's when I turn the key to turn on the car..) do you mean when you put the car into gear and start moving?  If the rattle occurs with key on in Park mode, can you get out of the car and tell where the rattle is coming from?